# Get Recording from Twilio during call

Tags: c#, twilio

I have this project, I need to make a call from twilio and record it (I already did it) but I need the recording during the call to use speech to text Google service and transcribe the call before ends. is it possible? or is any other platform like twilio that can provide access to the recording when is in process?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording

Comment: I read the documentation @ChetanRanpariya, also I complete the application in a different way:

*Start the Call
*Get the Recording (Because I can access to the information but I cant download it partial)
* (When the call ends) Download the recording
*Send it to Google and save the transcription in a txt file

Comment: But the client needs the transcription of the call before ends and that reference doesnt mention nothing like that

Comment: You might want to look at the Twilo documentation carefully and also raise a ticket with Twilio about the feature you want. Twilio Support system is good. The will respond with proper details.

Comment: I already create a ticket asking about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWilio doesnt have the ability of give you access to the recording during the call, they have another services like Speech Recongnition but this is a different thing.

Thanks